# Firebase messaging().onMessage() is not called when popup.html is open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have used fcm in my chrome extension.Now my firebase-messaging-sw.js is activated and 'setBackgroundMessageHandler' can be called correctly.But 'setBackgroundMessageHandler' callback is still called when popup.html is open.It seems that messaging().onMessage callback is  never called. How to fix it?

Here is my code.

---

```
// firebase-messaging-sw.js
....
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    let notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    let notificationOptions = {
        body: 'Background Message body.',
        icon: 'resource/icon_web.png'
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

```
// popup.js
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log('Message received. ', payload);
});
```

```sh
// request
curl -X POST \
  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
  -H 'Authorization: key=<xxx>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
   "data": {
      "title":"postman data title",
      "body": "postman data body"
   },
   "to":"<xxxx>"
}'
```

The console:

```
[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message  
{data: {…}, from: "153493200810", collapse_key: "do_not_collapse"}
```

BTW, I didn't put 'gcm_sender_id' in the manifest.json because chrome does not allow that.Is there anything to do with it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase but the problem may be caused by incorrect use of the extension architecture so it would make sense to show how exactly firebase-messaging-sw.js is registered/loaded/declared. It's also commonly misunderstood that the popup runs only when shown, each time anew.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your word reminds me the onMessage callback is registered in background.js and  the background.html will never come to the foreground. As a result, the onMessage is never called. :p

Comment: Did you find any reason why onMessage is not fired? I'm using manifest v3 and this problem still occurs.